# Understanding how to relate double values when output from byte array using println()?

Tags: java, arrays, double, byte, representation

### Edit: All, after some research I answered my own question.  In short, my code works fine but was missing a concept to understand the output. Thought to share for benefit of others. My confusion was from not understanding double precision representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). The byte array values [64 66 1 71 -82 20 122 -31] need to be converted to bits and then parsed according to the Wiki article.

I'm trying to understand the output of a small Java program I wrote for storing double values in byte arrays. This is the output and code follows. What is the format/representation/encoding (?) of the output "64 66 1 71 -82 20 122 -31" ? I've tried numerous online converters (hex, ascii, unicode, base64) to understand how the byte array element output represents the double 36.01. I know my code stores it in the byte array correctly, since I successfully tested it with another class that requires latitude expressed as a byte array, and be within a particular range.
Edit: new output with addition of Arrray.toString. But that does not address my question. I'll try again.
My initial thought was the first byte array element "66" was hex representation for decimal 3. But that's not so. Decimal 3 is hex 3 (checked with an online converter). So I'm confused as to what is the representation of the byte array elements. If this is the correct representation, then what value in the byte array represents what value in the double 36.01?. Hope that clarifies.

```
Output
latitude decimal format: 36.01
latitude raw byte format: [B@7f31245a
latitude bytes String.valueOf: [B@7f31245a
byte [] array values iterated via a loop... 36.01

64 66 1 71 -82 20 122 -31 

printed using Arrays.toString:[64, 66, 1, 71, -82, 20, 122, -31] 

system encodingProperty is: UTF-8

--------------------------
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ByteArrayFormat {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double latitude = 36.01;
        ByteArrayFormat test = new ByteArrayFormat();
        test.printByte(latitude);
    }// end main

    public void printByte (double latitude) {

        byte[] latitudeInDecimalDegreesBytes = ToByteArray(latitude);
        System.out.println("latitude decimal format: " + latitude);
        System.out.println("latitude raw byte format: " + latitudeInDecimalDegreesBytes);
        System.out.println("latitude bytes String.valueOf: "+ (String.valueOf(latitudeInDecimalDegreesBytes)));
        //System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("byte [] array values iterated via a loop... " + latitude);
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int i=0; i< latitudeInDecimalDegreesBytes.length ; i++) {
            System.out.print(latitudeInDecimalDegreesBytes[i] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("printed using Arrays.toString:" + Arrays.toString(latitudeInDecimalDegreesBytes) +" ");
        System.out.println("\n");
        String encodingProperty = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
        System.out.println("system encodingProperty is: " +encodingProperty);
    }

    public byte[] ToByteArray(double value) {
        byte [] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).putDouble(value).array();
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand?  What output were you expecting and how does your actual result not meet those expectations?

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString(latitudeInDecimalDegreesBytes)` when printing the `Array`